# joomla error after hosting it on shared server

Tags: joomla3.0, eaccelerator

I have designed a new joomla3 website. while developing on my computer it was working fine.
Once I had setup this on shared hosting using akeeba backup and kickstart restore tools.
Following error is reported:

```
Fatal error: Invalid opcode 153/1/8. in /home/myinnori/public_html/tawasr/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php on line 702
```

Can any one please help me out to solve the issue.

I have tried by enabling each set of variables in ".htaccess" file from "public_html" folder of my hosting account.

Update:

```
line 701    // Convert decimal
line 702    $source = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/m', function($m)
line 703    {
line 704    return utf8_encode(chr($m[1]));
line 705    }, $source
line 706    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an Issue regarding the inline function of php.
php on my server was not supporting inline function that had a call back.
I have used preg_replace() instead of preg_replace_callback() and the issue was solved. Use the following code, just keep the second parameter as empty string like below code

```
$source = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mi', "", $source
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

- please share source code of input.php page in here.
- i think your problem is about a disabled or limited library in your
  shared web hosting .
- if you have preg_replace function this is your problem ! according to
  php.net and for security reason many shared hosting offer to use
  preg_replace_callback() instead of preg_replace() but you can share
  input.php source code for better help

  http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

  special thanks

Comment: added the code to original question above. -thanks :)

Comment: I have tried by using both the functions preg_replace and preg_replace_callback but cant get the solution

Answer (score 0):

okay ,you should insert 2 line in your .htaccess file similar to below :

```
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

and adding below lines to your httpd.conf (contact to your hosting support center)

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
</IfModule>
```

source (forum.joomla.org)

Comment: You should also disable any opcode caching on the administrator side, it's not needed. - source(forum.joomla.org)